# How to download different Bluetooth Specification versions

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to find a simple repository or website which provides access to the Bluetooth Specification, with previous versions available. I have found this so far:

**BT Specification Versions Found** *(misc. sources)*

- [Bluetooth v1.1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimz-y2kaLTAhVY-mMKHSWSCuQQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.inf.ethz.ch%2Fpersonal%2Fhvogt%2Fproj%2Fbtmp3%2FDatasheets%2FBluetooth_11_Specifications_Book.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFEr0-S2VgJHyJNR_mKMf961hIRwQ&sig2=LPULz3PtmvaNRbMVOh6pCA&bvm=bv.152180690,d.cGc)
- [Bluetooth v2.0](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPr6ytkKLTAhUQwGMKHSJWDEQQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2Fdocman%2Fhandlers%2FDownloadDoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D40560&usg=AFQjCNGqplQS1QOQM7HoviDq05KvWspw3Q&sig2=y19GuR-oFHpVZvwgoncUaw&bvm=bv.152180690,d.cGc)
- [Bluetooth v4.2](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439)
- [Bluetooth v5.0](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043)

Is there a single repository for these instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is public on Bluetooth SIG's website:

- [Adopted specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications) for current *in force* documents
- [Legacy specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications/legacy-specifications) for superseded standards
- [Deprecated specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications/deprecated-specifications) for older standards that passed the deprecation period

Answer (score 1):

Here are links to the difference Bluetooth Specifications from the [Bluetooth SIG's website](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification) if interested:

**Bluetooth SIG Published Specifications**

- [Bluetooth v5.0](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043)
- [Bluetooth v4.2](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439)
- [Bluetooth v4.1](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=282159)
- [Bluetooth v4.0](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737)
- [Bluetooth v3.0 + HS](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=174214)
- [Bluetooth v2.1 + EDR](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=241363)
- [Bluetooth v2.0 + EDR](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=40560)

Thanks Nipo, you made it quite easy to find these!